# Excel formula Filter multiple rows into a single row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know if is possible to filter multiple rows into a single row.

Something like combine all filters bellow in only one row with values in same order excluding empty cells:

```
=FILTER(A1:D1;A1:D1<>"";"NO RESULTS")

=FILTER(A2:D2;A2:D2<>"";"NO RESULTS")

=FILTER(A3:D3;A3:D3<>"";"NO RESULTS")
```

Thanks!

[EXEMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N34Px.png)

Answer (score 1):

`FILTERXML()` can give expected result.

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&TEXTJOIN("</s><s>",TRUE,A1:D3)&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

To know more about [FILTERXML()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/5514747) read this by JvdV.

With beta channel of Excel-365 you can use `TOROW()` function.

```
=TOROW(A1:D3,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Harun24hr but the formula comes out #NAME? result, I'm not sure if it is because I am using MAC excel. 

Anyway many thanks for your promptly response!

Comment: Mac excel doesn’t support Filterxml().